# Как передать простой текст из первого фрагмента в textView второго фрагмента?

Tags: android-fragment, android, java

Есть 2 созданных фрагмента, как передать простой текст из первого фрагмента в textView второго фрагмента?

Comment: Например, `Intent`'ом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv2)).setText("Access from Fragment1");
```

Comment: И как же этот код решает задачу, озвученную в вопросе? ТС'у нужно из одного фрагмента изменить view другого фрагмента.